# Amplify PWM output from 3v3 to 10v using an amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, pwm

Actually I'm already using an amplifier to convert from 3v3 signal to 10v signal. Since different consideration like pin and board constrains, I'd like to use the same amplifier circuit to output also a PWM signal. So from 3v3 PWM get a 10V PWM.

Main problem is, when I generate a PWM from 1kHz to 10kHz (teorically maximum that I'll need) I've a very strange output.

I've tried two amplifier models:

NCS20074DR2G

OPA4196ID

Both of them acts in a same way (Yellow is PWM and Purple is Amplifier output):

[image]

Schematic that I'm using is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE7fmm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can see a gap between R5 and R2, actually this two resistor are directly connected. But I've some pads where I can put a capacitor or a resistor + led that are not mounted during test.

Are this two devices that I've tried suitable for this porpoise? Maybe I've too big resistors?

Another doubt that I've is why the output is cut in 4 steps? My 10V output is cutted in 2.5v steps.

Comment: I guess there is another problem. The amplifier should work.

Comment: Maybe a short on the amplifier output to a digital signal?